# How do you compare two images in javascript correctly?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, url

I'm using javascript in Tampermonkey (in Google Chrome) and I like to compare two images if they are identical / quite similar.

I thought I could do it by using a canvas element and compare the resulting strings, like that but no matter what images I choose, I always get that they are identical... : /

So the comparison doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why?

**Edit 1: Added a timer to wait for the images to load**
/

```
/ ==UserScript==
// @name         ImageCompare
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @match        www*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

var x = new Image();
var y = new Image();
var url_x = "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2010/03/google_logo.jpg";
var url_y = "https://nairobigarage.com/2017/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/6_logo_predesign.jpg";
x.src = 'chrome://favicon/' + url_x;
y.src = 'chrome://favicon/' + url_y;

var x_base64 = getBase64Image(x);
var y_base64 = getBase64Image(y);

sleep(5000).then(() => {
    if (x_base64 === y_base64)
    {
        alert("identical");
    }
    else
    {
       alert("not identical");
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to wait for the image(s) to load, you aren't currently doing that

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not sure if I got you correct but I have now added a delay of 5 seconds, it's still saying "identical" all the time :(

Comment: You put a delay on the comparison, not on waiting for the images to load.

Comment: Don’t add a delay. Add a `load` [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on each image.

Comment: Also since they are chrome:// protocol you more than likely will not be able to get the data url due to security restrictions.

Comment: @Xufox I'm not sure what that means but I understand it as to execute that piece of code if the page is loaded? If so, I have added the following and it still doesn't seem to work:

`window.onload = function () {
var x_base64 = getBase64Image(x);
var y_base64 = getBase64Image(y);

if (x_base64 === y_base64)
{`
   alert("identical");
}
else
{
   alert("not identical");
}}`

Comment: @cnmesr Not if the _page_ is loaded; execute the code once each _image_ is loaded. Hint: `x.addEventListener("load", `…`); y.addEventListener("load", `…`);`, though you’ll need a way to make sure, _both_ are loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait for the images to load, you can use the [`onload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) to notify you when the image has loaded

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = ()=>{
  //do work
};
```

So:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

var x = new Image();
var y = new Image();
var url_x = "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2010/03/google_logo.jpg";
var url_y = "https://nairobigarage.com/2017/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/6_logo_predesign.jpg";
x.src = 'chrome://favicon/' + url_x;
y.src = 'chrome://favicon/' + url_y;

//make the load events into promises
var xPromise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
   x.onload = resolve;
});
var yPromise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
   y.onload = resolve;
});
Promise.all([xPromise,yPromise]).then(()=>{
  var x_base64 = getBase64Image(x);
  var y_base64 = getBase64Image(y);
  if(x_base64 == y_base64){
    //match
  } else {
    //no match
  }
});
```

Note though you are trying to load resources from `chrome://` protocol, due to security restrictions you cannot actually get the data of cross origin resources. Either load resources from the same domain that your page is running, or use file inputs to get the image.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked for me! I only have the problem you mentioned in the end, I need to use resources from the same domain but I like to compare two images from two different domains. What do you mean by "use file inputs to get the image" ?

Comment: @cnmesr I mean `<input type="file">` where the user would pick a file from their own system. You could also use a proxy server, ie make a request to some script on your server which would then fetch the actual image and return that, but that won't work for `chrome://` urls.